# Cassandra Stess tool -Err:Application does not allow arbitrary arguments:write,yaml

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I am new to cassandra and java. I have been trying to use the new cassandra stress tool. I downloaded the Apache cassandra - https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/tools/stress

and when I run ant from the cassandra source directory it builds successfully but I am not able to run cassandra-stress tool with write or yaml parameters. I dont see the new options listed under cassandra-stress help

Error:
“Application does not allow arbitrary arguments:write,yaml=cqlstress-example.yaml.

How do I generate the new cassandra stress tool?

The cmd that I am using is cassandra-stress write -schema yaml=cqlstress-example.yaml
Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEKBy66h2wQ&list=PLqcm6qE9lgKJqAcRWqHz2I_CtO9FjC47E&index=6

Answer (score -2):

Was able to get the above error fixed.  http://pputhran.ghost.io/cassandra-stress-tool/

Comment: link is dead, you really should copy some of the solution here